# Get date when a word officially entered the English dictionary

Tags: python, linguistics

I am trying to track dates when different words entered the English dictionary (Oxford, Merriam-Webster, etc.)

I'd ideally like to find an API, so that if I sent 'selfie' I'd get back '2013' as part of the reply, but I think this data isn't very common or even easy to access.

I have looked at:

- http://www.collinsdictionary.com/api/
- http://developer.oxforddictionaries.com/

But neither seems to offer access to this data.

I am using `python` and have also taken a look on [pypi.python.org](http://pypi.python.org) but can't find any modules that would solve this problem yet.

Looks like I might just have to gather the data I am looking for by hand, but before doing that I wanted to check to see if anyone knew of a better way to go about this.

Comment: This is very specific task and has not much to do with programming. You just need to find some API that will share it. For example Collins Dictionary does has this information: http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tank (word origin section) but it is not specified if this information is returned via API. You can try to contact them.

Comment: Thanks Andrey, that is very helpful. You are correct, this is on the border of what I'd consider acceptable for an SO question. Do you think it would be better asked somewhere else? I had a look around but didn't see an SE site that was better suited. That said, if someone thinks it should be moved by all means go ahead.

Comment: As I pointed out both dictionaries (their web versions) include this data. So the first question is if they return it via API. I couldn't find any reference to that in their documentation. I think you better ask at some linguistics forum.

Comment: OK, will try that. If I find something I'll return and post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic script to retrieve words. If a word has multiple definitions, it chooses only one.

```
import re
import urllib2

# Import Custom libraries
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

def render_oxford_uri(term):
    '''
    Render the appropriate Oxford request uri
    '''
    base_url = "http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/"
    url = base_url + ("%s?q=%s" % (re.sub("\s+", "-", term), re.sub("\s+", "+", term)))
    return url

def get_words(*args):
    '''
    Oxford dictionary word scraper
    '''
    ret_list = []
    for term in args:
        request_uri = render_oxford_uri(term)
        request = urllib2.Request(request_uri, None, {})

        try:
            response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
            the_page = response.read()
        except Exception:
            the_page = ""

        if the_page:
            pool   = BeautifulSoup(the_page)
            result = pool.find("div", attrs={"class" : "entryPageContent"})

            if result:
                term        = result.find("h2"  , attrs={"class" : "pageTitle"})
                speech_part = result.find("span", attrs={"class" : "partOfSpeech"})
                definition  = result.find("span", attrs={"class" : "definition"})
                date        = result.find("span", attrs={"class" : "date"})

                cur_dict = \
                {
                    "Term"           : term.text,
                    "Part of Speech" : speech_part.text,
                    "Definition"     : definition.text,
                    "Date"           : date.text,
                }
                ret_list += [cur_dict]

    return ret_list

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print get_words("selfie", "vapid")
```